# Ich meine == I mean?

Tags: translation, usage

Today in my German class, I subconsciously said "`I mean`" and when I apologized for changing to English, my teacher said "Almost, you also say '`ich meine`'" in German.

Is this expression used so common and with the same way as in English or is there any difference?

Would `I mean that...` be translated as `Ich meine dass...` ?

Answer (score 12):

NO. It is not the same.
While there is an overlap I think the differences are more numerous.

> Ich meine, dass das nicht funktiniert.

Here, *meine* doesn't mean mean but rather *suspect*, *guess* or *be of the opinion*. In German, meinen is way more in the corner of *opinion* while the English *to mean* stretches toward *information* or *content*. You can also see that when you look at the corresponding nouns.

> meaning - die Bedeutung
>   Meinung - opinion

Those 2 are never a translation for each other. The word meinen is used in the same way as the English to mean, too but people would tend to use a different phrasing so as to avoid confusion with the above presented connotation.

> Was ich meine, ist...

Also, all phrasing like

> That means, what does that mean, I meant to say, what I mean with that, etc....

are rarely translated using *meinen*.

> Das heißt, was heißt das, Ich wollte sagen, was ich damit sagen will/meine...

Finally, the English filler *I mean* is only sometimes translated with  *meinen*.

Comment: thanks for the further details. I agree that to say "It's the same" is too much. But I understood the question that way, whether those phrases in general refer to the same meaning - and both do. So yes there are a lot of ways where you wouldn't translate them by replacing mean with meinen and the other way round. But it in most cases it is no mistake to do it. Right?

Comment: @Bertram Nudelbach... that's my point. I think in most cases it actually would be a mistake to do so.

Comment: however, I edited my answer with regard to the filler "I mean" ... sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 11):

Yes. It's the same. Even more weird is that `to be mean` is equal to `gemein sein`.

**EDIT**

Note that if you would say `The title means that..` you normally would translate it to `Der Titel bedeutet ...`. This is because only persons can `meinen` and things `bedeuten etwas` - the things mean something.

Comment: Bertram + @Luis Sep: I wish I could give +10 for the edit - this is such a common mistake these days. German "meinen" can only ever be used in connection with people, unless it's used indirectly: "The comment *was meant* as a compliment." = "Der Kommentar war als Kompliment *gemeint*." But I think you see the "human" aspect even here: that the *intention of the speaker* is in the focus here.

Comment: @Mac yes true, thanks ;) Your sentence can be extended with "The commentator meant the comment as a compliment." So it's not so easy but I think it's important to decide "who means?" So if a human means, it's "meinen" - if a thing means it's "bedeuten". So in your example "The comment means agreement." would be "Der Kommentar bedeutet Zustimmung".

Comment: Maybe a hint could be, if you can use "think" then "mean" means "meinen". If you can't, it means "bedeuten".

Comment: And would you say that "mean" means "bedeuten" when you can substitute for "translate"/"übersezten"?

Comment: Yes. Even if you normally can't just substitute means by translate .. but I would translate "to mean" in terms of translation always with "bedeuten".

Answer (score 2):

*meinen* has many definitions: *think* (denken, glauben), *mean* (sagen wollen), *intend*. 
Using *meinen* can lead to confusion sometimes. I would rather say: *Was ich eigentlich sagen wollte ist, dass …*